# Laravel factories return value (in afterCreating hook)

Tags: php, laravel, factories

I am creating a factory and using the "afterCreating" hook to insert some relationships.

This is the code:

```
$factory->define(MyModel::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name'                          => $faker->name
    ];
});

$factory->afterCreating(MyModel::class, function ($my_model, $faker) {

    // Make changes to my model, add relationships to it

    return $my_model; // or return "test"
});
```

My question is how to I return the modified model, the one modified in afterCreating()? Is it even possible to do so?

What I get returned is the original model that was created in the first method. The [Laravel Documentation API](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factory.html) states that it returns $this, which tells me it's the instance of the afterCreating, but it doesn't.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up the return value of the method `afterCreating` with the return value of your callback function.
To answer your question: yes it is possible and you have already written the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

Factory callbacks are registered using the `afterMaking` and `afterCreating` methods, and allow you to perform additional tasks after making or creating your model.

The return value of the method `afterCreating` is [$this](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factory.html#method_afterCreating) which means that the instanced model (if affected) is already based on the action within the function afterCreating. These callbacks are for example a clean way to save relational data automatically after creating a new model via a factory.

```
$factory->afterCreating(MyModel::class, function ($myModel, $faker) {
    $myModel->items()->save(factory(Item::class)->make());
});
```